# How to save a list item in a SharePoint asset library using CSOM with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, csom, assetslibrary

I am creating an App for SharePoint Online and I have a question: How can I insert a list item (audio file) in a SharePoint asset library using CSOM with JavaScript? is that possible?

Thanks